# How I can make my graphical layouts suitable for all the devices with different resolutions

Tags: android

I have created a money mangement application and till now everything goes well without any problem but unfortunately when I tested it on different devices I noticed that my graphical layouts of the xml files in real devices are not the same as what I set in my emualtor and it is different in different real devices for example on one device my buttons margins are less or more and can not be seen.
pls advise me how I can make it suitable for all the devices as it is my final project of university and it is my first experience and do not have much information on android pls tell me in detailed.

Thanks all,
Maryam

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 3):

You can find giudelines to support multiple screens in following links:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

You can start from there, hope it helps.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You need to create `different layout folder for the different screen of devices`.

By default, Android resizes your application layout to fit the current device screen. In most cases, this works fine. In other cases, your UI might not look as good and might need adjustments for different screen sizes. For example, on a larger screen, you might want to adjust the position and size of some elements to take advantage of the additional screen space, or on a smaller screen, you might need to adjust sizes so that everything can fit on the screen.

The configuration qualifiers you can use to provide size-specific resources are small, normal, large, and xlarge. For example, layouts for an extra-large screen should go in layout-xlarge/.

For more info, please refer [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support).